# Convert date with nsdateformatter in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have the following dates as String:

```
2018-06-14T23:00:00.000Z
2018-06-14T00:00:00.000Z
```

and I am trying to convert with this code:

```
let fecha_finConvert = convert_fecha(fecha: dateString)
func convert_fecha(fecha: String)-> String{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "es_EC")
    let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: fecha)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd 'de' MMM 'del' yyyy"
    let fecha_convert = dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!)

    return fecha_convert
}
```

and that should return value as:
14 de Jun. del 2018

the first date returns good BUT with the second date returns 13 de Jun. del 2018

What is wrong? How can I solve that?
thanks in advance

Comment: The time zone in Ecuador is UTC-0500. The date formatter considers the local time zone. `2018-06-14T00:00:00 +0000` and `2018-06-13T19:00:00 -0500` are the same point in time

Comment: Also note that you can set the output format more easily as `dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("ddMMMyyyy")` and you can be sure it will be localized correctly for your locale.

Comment: Even better than using a template is to use a `dateStyle`. Avoid using formats to display a date to a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both dates have the UTC (zero) timezone and they are being converted to your local time zone. Therefore the result is completely correct relative to your time zone.

If you want to display the dates in UTC time zone, you can set the time zone explicitly on the formatter:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

Comment: Excelent my friend :D :D Thanks

Comment: @Israel Please be sure you understand this. Do not add this line if you wish to show the dates in local time. Only do this if you want to show the dates in UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

In your time string - `2018-06-14T00:00:00.000Z` - you specify time zone - `Z` stands for `Zulu` time, which basically means `UTC` time zone.

When you convert your `dateObj` to a string, you need to specify `timeZone` property of your `dateFormatter`. If you don't specify it, it defaults to system time zone. I'm guessing your device's time zone is not `UTC`, hence the difference.